# Processing multiple forms in nodejs and postgresql

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, body-parser

I'm trying to process multiple forms with fieldset inside
This is a test for 40 questions, each question with 4 answers.
I need to get each answer from radio button that the users picks and use it to count correct answers.

I have some comments along the code to help out, if anything is needed let me know.
Thanks for any help.

My index.js code

```
import express from "express";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import pg from "pg";

const db = new pg.Client({
  user: "postgres",
  host: "localhost",
  database: "world",
  password: "***", // don't post your password!
  port: 5432,
});

const pool = new pg.Pool({
  user: "postgres",
  host: "localhost",
  database: "world",
  password: "***",
  port: 5432,
});

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

db.connect();
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

// Shuffling function based of fisher yates algorithm
const shuffle = array => {
  for (let i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    const temp = array[i];
    array[i] = array[j];
    array[j] = temp;
  }
}

let questions = [];

app.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  //Generates random of questions IDs.

  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    let questionId = Math.floor(Math.random() * 70);
    questions.push(questionId);
  };
  // Query questions IDs from DB and shuffles the answers
  let arrayToShuff = [];
  let shuffledArray = [];
  const result = await pool.query(`SELECT * FROM theoryhebrew WHERE questionid = ANY($1::int[])`, [questions]);

  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    arrayToShuff = [result.rows[i].answer1, result.rows[i].answer2, result.rows[i].answer3, result.rows[i].answer4];
    shuffle(arrayToShuff);
    shuffledArray = [arrayToShuff[0], arrayToShuff[1], arrayToShuff[2], arrayToShuff[3]];
    result.rows[i].answer1 = shuffledArray[0];
    result.rows[i].answer2 = shuffledArray[1];
    result.rows[i].answer3 = shuffledArray[2];
    result.rows[i].answer4 = shuffledArray[3];
  };

  return res.render("index.ejs", {
    questionsResults: result.rows,
    answersShuffled: shuffledArray
  });
});

for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  let questionId = Math.floor(Math.random() * 70);
  questions.push(questionId);
};

app.post("/submit", async (req, res) => {
  const submittedAnswer = req.body.answer;
  res.send(req.body);
  console.log(req.body);
  const result2 = await db.query(`SELECT answer1 FROM theoryhebrew WHERE questionid = ANY($1::int[])`, [questions]);
  const correctAnswer = result2.rows[0].answer1;

  if (submittedAnswer == correctAnswer) {
    console.log("This is correct");
  } else {
    console.log("Sorry, this is incorrect");
  }


});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running at http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

My index.ejs file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="he" dir="rtl">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>שאלות תאוריה</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/main.css">
</head>

<body>
  <% questionsResults.forEach(question=> { %>
    <form action="/submit" method="post" name="<%= question.questionid %>">
      <fieldset form="<%=question.questionid %>">
        <legend>
          <%= question.questiontext %>
        </legend>
        <div>
          <input type="radio" id="answer1" name="answer" value="<%= question.answer1 %>" checked />
          <label for="answer1">
            <%= question.answer1 %>
          </label>
        </div>
        <div>
          <input type="radio" id="answer2" name="answer" value="<%= question.answer2 %>" />
          <label for="answer2">
            <%= question.answer2 %>
          </label>
        </div>
        <div>
          <input type="radio" id="answer3" name="answer" value="<%= question.answer3 %>" />
          <label for="answer3">
            <%= question.answer3 %>
          </label>
        </div>
        <div>
          <input type="radio" id="answer4" name="answer" value="<%= question.answer4 %>" />
          <label for="answer4">
            <%= question.answer4 %>
          </label>
        </div>


        <h2>
          מספר שאלה לפי מאגר שאלות: <%= question.questionid %>
        </h2>
      </fieldset>
    </form>


    <% }) %>
      <button type="submit">שלח תשובה</button>


      <!-- <form class="container" action="/submit" method="post">
    <div class="horizontal-container">
      <h3>
        Total Score:
        <span id="score">
          
        </span>
      </h3>

    </div>

    

  </form>
  <script>
    var wasCorrect = "<%= locals.wasCorrect %>";
    console.log(wasCorrect)
    if (wasCorrect === "false") {
      alert('Game over! Final best score: <%= locals.totalScore %>');
      document.getElementById("app").innerHTML = '<a href="/" class="restart-button">Restart</a>'
    }


  </script> -->
</body>

</html>
```